# AnyLogic: free specific agents from wait block

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I have equipped my agent with a parameter barcode. Input is an Excel with different barcodes as arrival in the source.

[image]

There are four different types of parts in my model. Part 1 is multiplied in the model by a split block w times, part 2 x times, part 3 y times and part 4 z times.

The parts run different paths through my model. That means they have different times and therefore do not arrive back in the sink at the same time. Because I want all parts to end up in the sink at the same time, I want to work with a wait block.

When the parts are multiplied, they keep their unique barcode.

Example: Part 3 is multiplied y times. So there are y many part 1 with the same barcode. So in the wait block I want all agents (parts) to wait until ALL multiplied parts of this part arrive in the wait block just before the sink.

My approach is: a switch case within the wait block after Part 1, Part 2 ect.
And then inside the case a code like: `if w agents with the same barcode are inside the wait block, free them`. But not all other agents. So you could say that this wait block is like a sorting station.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this differently. Instead of `Wait` block, I would keep it as `Queue`. Then join it to a `Pickup` block. Inside `Pickup`, select `While condition is true` and type below the condition (assuming your total number should be 7) `(agent.barcode==container.barcode) && (count(queue, q-> q.barcode==agent.barcode)==7 )`
.

Whenever a new barcode enters the system, create a dummy agent with `agent.barcode` set to that value and send the dummy agent to `enter1` with code like `enter1.take(agent)`. Then this dummy agent will wait in `queue2`, once the count is reached, it will pick up exactly that number of agents and depart to sink. If you want, you can put a `Dropoff` block and then `Sink`.

[image]

Comment: First of all, thank you very much Yashar! You helped me a lot. :)
But one thing doesn't work. I adjusted everything in my model as you suggested, but in my scenario the dummy agent doesn't wait in queue2. Acutally it just goes trough. How did you get it to work in your model? Do you have an idea where my fault can be? Thanks in advance.

Comment: they wait in pickup internal queue, which is not a problem per se!

Comment: Hey @Yashar: I don't think that solves my question :) Look at this screenshot of my running model: imgur.com/a/hXOj4YD In a short period of time, all the dummy (copy) agents went through and did unfortunately not wait in queue2 (or internal queue of pickup). Because at first the queue of the originals is empty, the copy agents are not waiting. Do you have an idea? In my case your answer doesn't work..

Comment: Fixed my problem. I implemented a wait-block instead of queue2 which frees all agents at once, if queue has a specific length. Also I deleted the second term in Yashars condition. So only `(agent.caseNumber == container.caseNumber)`. I will mark this question as answered, but if someone has an explanation why this doesn't work feel free to comment.